# Fetch authorized friends using graph library v2.4

Tags: ios

I want to fetch Facebook user friends in my app using v2.4 graph library. I am getting count not names. I am not able to get authorized friends. Any help would be appreciable ?

// Function

```
-(void)fetchFriends
{
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                      initWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                                      parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"}
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"data : %@",result);
        }];
    }

}
```

// Response

```
data : {
    data =     (
    );
    summary =     {
        "total_count" = 3;
    };
}
```

// Expected Response

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "id": "id"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "Getting link here"
  },
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 1
  }
}
```

// Permissions

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": "user_friends",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "public_profile",
      "status": "granted"
    }
  ]
}
```

It is working on Graph API Explorer but not in my app.